# "...focuses on the person’s individual motivation to pursue skills,..."

Tags: word-meaning

I read a sentence on a video but am not sure what does "motivation" means in it.

Does it mean "enthusiasm for doing something" or "the need or reason for doing something" in the following sentence?

> Some of the principles behind IE, intellectual entrepreneurship,
> specifically its intellectual aspect, focuses on the person’s
> individual
> ***motivation*** to pursue skills, expertise, and knowledge in one area, the development of what I call
> the "unique intellectual capital", the individual’s set of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `motivate` means: make someone want to do something.

I will give an example:

> I am hungry. I am **motivated** to eat. My hunger **motivates** me to eat. The grocery store is far away. I do not want to walk to the store, so I am **motivated** to ride my bike. The far distance **motivates** me to ride my bike.

Another example, for your specific sentence:

> I want to get a better job, so I will learn new skills. I am **motivated** to learn new skills. I have **motivation** to learn new skills, because I will get a better job. I have **a motivation** to learn new skills because it will be good for me. The potential for a new job **motivates** me to learn new skills.

Comment: what a lovely answer. I know there is blur area between these two words for the word motivation or there is not huge difference in terms of meaning but which word would you choose if you want to replace the word motivation with "reason" and "enthusiasm" in my sentence.

Comment: I would do a direct swap-out of "motivation" for "reason". These two sentences mean basically the same thing: 1) "Some principles focus on the person's motivations to pursue skills." 2) "Some principles focus on the person's reasons to pursue skills."  ............... I think that 'enthusiasm' doesn't do a good job saying that there is a goal trying to be achieved. For example, "I am enthusiastic about riding bikes", may be just because I enjoy riding bikes. However, "I am motivated to ride bikes", sounds more like I have a goal, that I'm training to win a race or to become healthy.